Python Access Google Bigquery Fails [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)
I'm new to both Python and Big Query, but I have a vendor that hosts big query data for us.  They gave us a json file, and it works fine when I use power bi to access the data.
Wanted to pull the data into python and all I get is:

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000) after 10 minutes.

I tried this off the corporate network and on, so doesn't appear to be firewall related.  Just running on local desktop.
Code is below:
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '<filename>.json'

client = bigquery.Client()

sql_query = """
select *
from `<project>.<folder>.<table>`
LIMIT 50"""

query_job = client.query(sql_query)

for row in query_job.result():
  print(row)

After 10 minutes, I get

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)


Are you running (a) on Windows? (b) Power BI and the Python code (i) on the same machine? (ii) using the same credentials? The error suggests that the certificate chain that your Python code is using is... incorrect. What happens if you (run a Python REPL and) import requests then requests.get("https://bigquery.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest",verify=True)? The verify=True is the default but I'd expect you to receive a similar error.

Please don't os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '<filename>.json'. The Google library implements logic for finding the credentials only one path of which involves the environment variable being set. By doing this, you're forcing one path which is an anti-pattern. It's preferable to  APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS=<filename>.json python yourcode.py if you wish this path to be taken.

(a) Yes, windows.  (b) Both are running on same desktop using the same json file.  It's just a command line python script.   The requests does return the same error (much faster).

Not a Windows user so can't help further. That Power BI on the machine works, suggests that your system's root certificates are up-to-date but that Python isn't accessing them. Ensure Python is current. Hopefully someone familiar with Windows can help.
